# Collapse Navbar when route changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just added ui-bootstrap to my package based on the angular-fullstack-generator. Before that I used the following code to collapse the navbar on small devices when the route changes:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, next) {
  // collapse navbar
  angular.element('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

This is not possible anymore because of the directives as I understand from #1672 but how I can manually collapse the navbar then?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Can you provide the code of your navbar, that way it's easier to suggest changes

Comment: of course, it's all here: https://github.com/Kageetai/JayMap/tree/master/client/components/navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse the navbar on click (it feels more natural to me) simply by adding (or enhancing) the `ng-click` handler on each `<a>`:

```
<a ng-href="{{item.link}}" ng-click="isCollapsed=true">{{item.title}}</a>
<a href="" ng-click="isCollapsed=true;changeLanguage('en')">{{ 'LANG_BUTTON_EN' | translate }}</a>
```

---

If you really want it after the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, add the same event listener to your `navbar.controller.js` (no need to listen to the `$rootScope` though - or is this event limited there? I do not know so please use caution):

```
angular.module('jayMapApp')
    .controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $translate, Auth) {
        ...
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, next) {
            $scope.isCollapsed = true;
        });
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution works fine and I like it more to not clutter the markup that much. And of course you're right, I don't need to use the $rootScope

Comment: Yes, the markup gets dirtier this way. I usually do not place code in the markup; but I make an exception for isolated cases like the navbar.

Comment: Oh and I noticed only the dropdown in the navbar is closing and  not the navbar itself when I click one of the languages links in there. Is there maybe a way to also close that? Does it have to do with the scope of the navbar?

Comment: You will have to do something in the lines of solution 1 (if you don't want to pollute the HTML with code, call a function of the controller). However you do it, the language-change links must also set `isCollapsed` to `true`. If done with the event, it will only work on route links, not the other links in the navbar, as the other links do not broadcast the `$stateChangeSuccess` event.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course `$stateChangeSuccess´ does not run on the language links.
I just have the `$scope.isCollapsed = true;` in my function to change the language too. That seems easier and works too.